# c++: How can i create a receipt that will show the chosen item(s) and their quantity, price and total price

Tags: c++

Im tryin to create a receipt for my ordering program. How can i create a receipt that will show the chosen item(s) and their quantity, price and total price?

already tried reading some receipt references but cant understand coz im still learning c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

 char acoustic, electric, drums, piano, music, equip, Yes, No, y;

 int pay1, pay2, pay3, pay4, pay5, quantity1, quantity2, quantity3, 
quantity4, quantity5;
std::string again;

int main()
{
cout << "Welcome to the Music Shop" << endl <<endl;
cout << "                                                                         ===========================                            "<<endl;
cout << "                                                                         |       Categories        |                            "<<endl;
cout << "                                                                         |  [a] Acoustic Guitar    |                            "<<endl;
cout << "                                                                         |  [b] Electric Guitar    |                            "<<endl;




do {    
cout << "                                                                     Choose from the available categories:";
cin >> music;
cout << ""<<endl;

switch (music)
{
    case 'a':

    cout << "                                                             =============================================== "<<endl;
    cout<< "                                                             |                Acoustic Guitars             |" << endl;
    cout<< "                                                             |                                             |" << endl;
    cout<< "                                                             |           Product                 Price     |" << endl;
    cout<< "                                                             | [1] Fender Acoustic Guitar      P6,900.00   |" << endl;
    cout<< "                                                             | [2] Hartwood Acoustic Guitar    P6,300.00   |" << endl;
    cout << "                                                             =============================================== "<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"                                                                Choose from the available Acoustic Guitars:";
    cin>>acoustic;

    if (acoustic == '1'){
        cout<<"Enter the quantity:";
        cin>>quantity1;
        cout<<"("<<quantity1<<")"<<"Fender Acoustic Guitar was added to your cart"<<endl;
        cout<<"Would you like to add more item? (Yes/No)"<<endl;
        cin>>again;

    }
    else if (acoustic == '2'){
        cout<<"Enter the quantity:";
        cin>>quantity1;
        cout<<"("<<quantity1<<")"<<"Hartwood Acoustic Guitar was added to your cart"<<endl;
        cout<<"Would you like to add more item? (Yes/No)"<<endl;
        cin>>again;
    }
    else {
        cout<<"Invalid"<<endl;
    }

    break;

    case 'b':

    cout << "                                                             =============================================== "<<endl;
    cout<< "                                                             |                Electric Guitars             |" << endl;
    cout<< "                                                             |                                             |" << endl;
    cout<< "                                                             |           Product                 Price     |" << endl;
    cout<< "                                                             | [1] Gibson Electric Guitar      P8,500.00   |" << endl;
    cout<< "                                                             | [2] Ibanez Electric Guitar      P25,000.00  |" << endl;
    cout << "                                                             =============================================== "<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"                                                                Choose from the available Electric Guitars:";
    cin>>electric;

        if (electric=='1'){           
        cout<<"Enter the quantity:";
        cin>>quantity1;
        cout<<"("<<quantity1<<")"<<"Gibson Electric Guitar was added to your cart"<<endl;
        cout<<"Would you like to add more item? (Yes/No)"<<endl;
        cin>>again; 
    }
        else if (electric=='2'){                
        cout<<"Enter the quantity:";
        cin>>quantity1;
        cout<<"("<<quantity1<<")"<<"Ibanez Electric Guitar was added to your cart"<<endl;
        cout<<"Would you like to add more item? (Yes/No)"<<endl;
        cin>>again;
    }
    else {
        cout<<"Invalid";
    } 
        break;
    default: 
      cout<<"Invalid"<<endl;
 }

   }
```

and here after inputting No i want it proceed to the summary of receipt

```
     while (again == "Yes" || again == "yes");

  cout<<"***********************************Music Shop***********************************"<<endl;
  cout<<"Name of Item                       Quantity   Price           Total Price       "<<endl;
  cout<<"                                                                                "<<endl;
  return 0;

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use two maps for data storage. One for the prices, this is just initialized at the beginning and it has the different guitars (or any identifier of the guitars) as key and their price as value. A second map is filled while the cart is being filled.

```
int main()
{
    // ############## Here is the important part ######################
    map<string, double> price_list = {{"ga1", 6900.0}, {"ga2", 6300.0}, {"ge1", 8500.0}, {"ge2", 25000.0}};
    map<string, int> quantities;

    do {
    cin >> music;
    switch (music)
    {
        case 'a':
            cin>>acoustic;
            if (acoustic == '1'){
                cin>>quantity1;

                // Add the value to the already selected quantities.
                quantities["ga1"] += quantity1 - '0';
                cin>>again;
            }
            else if (acoustic == '2'){
                cin>>quantity1;

                // Add the value to the already selected quantities.
                quantities["ga2"] += quantity1 - '0';
                cin>>again;
            }
            else {
                cout<<"Invalid"<<endl;
            }
            break;

        case 'b':
            cin>>electric;

            if (electric=='1'){           
                cin>>quantity1;

                // Add the value to the already selected quantities.
                quantities["ge1"] += quantity1 - '0';
                cin>>again; 
            }
            else if (electric=='2'){
                cin>>quantity1;

                // Add the value to the already selected quantities.
                quantities["ge2"] += quantity1 - '0';
                cin>>again;
            }
            else {
                cout<<"Invalid";
            } 
            break;
        default: 
          cout<<"Invalid"<<endl;
    }
    } while (again == "Yes" || again == "yes");

  cout<<"***********************************Music Shop***********************************"<<endl;
    // ... ... ...
    for(auto it = quantities.begin(); it != quantities.end(); ++it){
        cout << it->first << it->second << price_list[it->first] << price_list[it->first] * it->second << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;

 }
```

This will print your receipt, here the names of the guitars are simply ga1, ga2, ge1, ge2, but you can enter whatever you want, or have an extra lookup table where you map ids to strings etc. If you wonder, why it says `quantities["ga1"] += quantity1 - '0';` This is to convert the char of a number to the actual number to add it to an integer.